# how to implement arrayList for objects

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I am trying to pass in values to Super class called "Account", then store each obj into an array list.

My code for class Account

```
abstract class account{
  String number;
  String  name;
  int amount;
  int newbalance;
  static final int balance = 1000;
  int bal;

  public  account(){
    // used to store the parameter passed into constructor

  }



  int deposit(int i) {
    return i;

  }

  void withdrawal(int i){

  }

  public void setData(String string, String string2, int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  public void showData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

}
```

In my main method, I want to create an object then pass in values for name , number, and amount which are to be stored in the array list because i want to have multiple objects with different names number and amount stored for them. then i want to access the child class "Sbaccount" and update the "newbalance" variable

My code for main

```
public class oopassignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String type;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("What type of account do you want to create? :");
        type=input.nextLine();
        
         Account sb;
          sb = new sbaccount();
          
          //sb.setData("Jospeh", "0563994",50000);
          sb.setData("Joohn", "009734",50000);
          sb.setData("hope", "05634",50000);
          ArrayList <sbaccount> usera = new ArrayList<sbaccount>();
          usera.add((sbaccount) sb);
         usera.add((sbaccount) sb);
          for (int i = 0; i < usera.size(); i++){
        usera.get(i).showData();
           //userb.
          }
}
```

And my code for the child class "sbaccount"

```
final class sbaccount extends Account {
  int total = 0;

  public  sbaccount(){
    super ();

  }
  public void setData(String  name, String  number, int  amount){

    this.name = name;
    this.number= number;
    this.amount= amount;
  }
  public void showData(){
    System.out.println("Account Owner: "+name);
    System.out.println("Account number: "+ number);
    System.out.println("Your New Amount is "+ newbalance);

    System.out.println("Your Account Balance is: $"+ total);
    return;
  }
  int deposit ( int money){
    newbalance = money + amount;

    System.out.println("Hi "+ name
        +" \nAccountnumber: "+ number
        +" \nYou have deposited :$"+money);
    System.out.println("\nYour Account balance is now :"+ newbalance);
    return newbalance;

  }
  void withdrawal(int withdraw){
    int total = 0;
    total = bal - withdraw;
    if (total <= balance){
      System.out.println("Your balance is too low for withdrawal!");

    }
    else{
      System.out.println("\nHi "+ name
          +" \nAccountnumber: "+ number
          +" \nYou have Withdrawn :$"+withdraw);
      System.out.println("\nYour Account balance is now :"+ total);
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I think you've forgot to say what your problem is.

Comment: Hi @Amongalen ! my question is after i compile when i try to retrieve the data from the array list i am unable to retrieve the already stored data. 1) my object don't seem to be storing it properly in the array? value it keeps getting override. 2)how do i retrieve the data from the array list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend you to make the first letter of each class name capitalized as per the [official naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)

After that, I dont see any compilation error in your code. And as far as your question is concerned, you have implemented arraylist for objects successfully.

One more thing, I would like to say here is that, you dont need to cast the object before adding to the list coz it's child class of the parent type.

i.e instead of writing

```
usera.add((sbaccount) sb);
```

simply use

```
usera.add( sb);
```

---

Edit:

So your question is why the values in your object keeps on getting overriden? The answer is simple. It's because you have written

```
         sb.setData("Joohn", "009734",50000);
          sb.setData("hope", "05634",50000);
```

Which means first you are setting data in "sb" object and then you are updating the data in the same "sb" object.

To store both the data in the array list, you just need two objects, say sb1 and sb2..

```
         Account sb1 = new Sbaccount();
         sb1.setData("Joohn", "009734",50000);
         Account sb2 = new Sbaccount();
         sb2.setData("hope", "05634",50000);

 ....
        usera.add(sb1);
        usera.add(sb2);
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhinaba! my question is after i compile when i try to retrieve the data from the array list i am unable to retrieve the already stored data. 
1) my object don't seem to be storing it properly in the array? value it keeps getting override.
2)how do i retrieve the data from the array list?

Comment: @OlawaleGeorge  I have updated my answer to this question. You are retrieving data from the array list in correct way although there are many other ways to do the same.